# Accessing "this" Type JavaScript Variables From Other Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, member-variables

I have an event firing and even though it's inside of the function from which I'm trying to access variables, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined`.  So, let's say:

```js
( function($) {

    $.fn.main = function() {

        this.setting = 1;

        $("#someElement").scroll( function() {

            console.debug(this.setting);

        } );

    }

} )(jQuery);
```

I'm sure it has something to do with timing, but then again, I could be wrong.  Should I make a copy of `this` and make that public?  Anyone?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` cannot be pinned in a closure as the `this` gets its value dynamically.

try :

```
var self = this;
```

And reference self.

Comment: I like your simplicity, though you all got it right.  Thanks.  Definitely what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy  `this` to another variable

```
( function($) {

    $.fn.main = function() {

        this.setting = 1;
        var that = this;
        $("#someElement").scroll( function() {

            console.debug(that.setting);

        } );

    }

} )(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( function($) {

    $.fn.main = function() {

        this.setting = 1; // "this" refers to the "$.fn.main" object

        $("#someElement").scroll( function() {

            console.debug(this.setting); // "this" refers to the "$('#someElement')" object

        } );

    }

} )(jQuery);
```

If you want to use the `this` from `$.fn.main`, you can store the variable. The following would work:

```
( function($) {

    $.fn.main = function() {

        var that = this

        that.setting = 1; // "this.setting" would also work

        $("#someElement").scroll( function() {

            console.debug(that.setting); // You need to reference to the other "this"

        } );

    }

} )(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `this` inside the scroll method is refereing to the scroll method. The method is bound to be called on the scroll event of element with id 'someElement'. and the scope of the binding object is lost.