# How to access an instance variable within a Promise callback?

Tags: javascript, this, jquery-deferred

Let's say I have a basic dumb javascript class :

```
var FunctionX = function(configs) {
this.funcConfigs = configs;
}

FunctionX.prototype.getData = function() {
  return $.get('/url');
}

FunctionX.prototype.show = function(promise) {
  console.log(this.funcConfigs); // <-- this here is the promise itself, I'm looking to get the instance's configs
}

FunctionX.prototype.setup = function() {
  this.GetData().then(show);
}

var f = new FunctionX({ "a": "b" });
f.setup();
```

Now I'm trying here in the show function to access the instance variable "funcConfig". "This" is the promise, and "funcConfigs" directly returns undefined.

I tried to resolve this issue with a `.resolveWith(this)` but it does not solve this issue.

How can I access the instances variables in this scope context?

Comment: Nothing to do with promises, only `this` in functions invoked with different contexts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561723/this-in-callback-functions , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this-context?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120271/accessing-this-type-javascript-variables-from-other-functions?rq=1 and similar

Comment: I put back in the jquery-deferred tag for use of [`resolveWith`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/), which tries to approach the problem from the opposite way (e.g. specifies a context, doesn't bind to an existing context). If that "does not solve the issue" then `this` is already wrong in the context `resolveWith` is used.

Comment: Does that code actually run? I could understand `this.getData().then(this.show);` (though you may still have the same issue).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In agreement with `user2864740`, the issue is most likely caused because `this` is not what you expect it to be when `show` is invoked as a callback.  To make this work properly, you need to capture the proper `this` in a closure (e.g. `var that = this;`), and invoke it explicitly.

In other words...

```
FunctionX.prototype.setup = function() {
   var that = this;

   this.getData().then(function () {
      that.show();
   });
}
```

EDIT: For a slightly cleaner syntax (using underscore.js):

```
FunctionX.prototype.setup = function() {
   var that = this;

   this.getData().then(_.bind(this.show, this));
}
```

Comment: Yep but then it defeats completely the goal of the use of promises which is to chain to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I agree with you about defeating the purpose of promises. We're still using the callback nature of promises to chain functions together, we're just chaining a new function that wraps the existing function.  If it's just a matter of cleaner syntax, see my edit.

Comment: Where did underscore suddenly come from?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot it comes from underscorejs (http://underscorejs.org/#bind). The idea is nice but I can't use UnderscoreJS. Fortunately enough, the native js function bind was enough to solve the problem via `this.getData().then(this.show.bind(this));`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Fair question, I prefer the original syntax, it's not worth pulling in underscore.js just for this purpose, but useful if you're already using it for other things.

Comment: @Erick The native .bind function achieves the same result, but beware of browser compatibility.  In particular, it looks like this function only works in IE9+, similar support issues on all other modern browsers. This may be fine, just wanted to point it out.